# Does pry or irb allow you to work interactively from inside a block?

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I know that pry allows you to "cd" into other scopes.

```
pry(main)> cd Object
pry(Object)> ls
constants: 
  ARGF               Encoding          GC              NIL                  
  ArgumentError      EncodingError     Gem             NilClass             
  ARGV               Enumerable        Hash            Noexec               
  Array              Enumerator        IndexError      NoMemoryError        
...
```

But is there any way to move the interactive session into a block thats passed to a method?

```
pry(main)> cd some_instance.some_method do |some_argument|
pry(block)> ls
  some_argument        some_other_vars_available_within_block
pry(block)> end
  result_of_block
pry(main)>
```

If possible, this would be exceedingly helpful. I've tried getting binding.pry to work myself in this fashion, without some luck, but I wanted to make sure I'm going down the right path before I continue.

Comment: I doubt doing it like that would work, but you can put a `binding.pry` in the block.

Comment: @rogerdpack, how would you do this in ruby-debug aside from inserting a `debugger` statement? (which u could do with pry too, by just inserting a `binding.pry` statement)

Comment: you can instruct it to break "wherever you want" (I'm not sure of a method for saying proc.step_into_this with ruby-debug, though it might exist, you can break by line number).  In general though, like with pry (I guess) you'd need to start with ruby-debug at some point to setup the breakpoints...

Comment: It worked great! Once I got my own system-related issue out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i understand you fully, but you can try this, for example:

```
(master ✘)✹✭ ᐅ pry
[1] pry(main)> def hello(&block)
             |   Object.new.instance_exec(&block)
             | end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> block_binding = nil
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> hello { |some_argument = "testing"| u = 20; block_binding = binding }
=> #<Binding:0x007fdd33b1f680>
[4] pry(main)> cd block_binding
[5] pry(#<Object>):1> ls
locals: _  __  _dir_  _ex_  _file_  _in_  _out_  _pry_  _super  block_binding  some_argument  u
[6] pry(#<Object>):1> some_argument
=> "testing"
[7] pry(#<Object>):1> u
=> 20
[8] pry(#<Object>):1> self
=> #<Object:0x007fdd33b1f888>
[9] pry(#<Object>):1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it turns out that nesting `pry` works beautifully. Kudos to the `pry` team.

Once I got my little binding.pry issue out of the way (my fault entirely).

**Nesting `pry`:** *(note the 2 `exit` statements needed)*

```
Hershwild:~ jstillwell$ pry
[1] pry(main)> binding.pry
[1] pry(main)> exit
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> exit
Hershwild:~ jstillwell$
```

**Bringing forth `pry` from within a block:**

```
Hershwild:~ jstillwell$ pry
[1] pry(main)> def test
[1] pry(main)*   yield true
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> test do |inside|
[2] pry(main)*   binding.pry
[2] pry(main)* end  
# after that end statement, pry resumes inside the block
[1] pry(main)> inside
=> true
[2] pry(main)> exit
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> exit
Hershwild:~ jstillwell$
```

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed, I was testing some Gitlab code that depended on having a `Session.current` variable that is set in a block, and it works beautifully:
`pry(main)> Gitlab::Session.with_session({foo:'bar'}) { pry }`. Until you `exit` the session will correctly be set.